# Clear content in S:S when T:T contains "Copied" Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am stuck with, at first sight, simple script.

I want to clear a content from cell S when T has value "Copied".

What I have at the moment is this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart === 20) { 
    e.range.offset(0,-1).clearContent();
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to include IF. Also, bear in mind that T column has a formula, so I don't edit it manually, and with this script, it doesn't work.

It doesn't have to be OnEdit, I can set a trigger to run the script every minute which is even better, but it is important to filter it by the value Copied.

To explain a bit more how my file works (example):

1) I add a comment in the cell S5.

2) My second script runs every minute where it copies values from column S to column V.

3) In the column T, I have the formula (=IF(V5<>"",IF(RegExMatch(S5,V5),"Copied",""),"")), which means if the value exist in the column V5 add Copied in cell T5.

4) I am looking for a solution that when cell T:T has "Copied", delete the cell range S:S

Thank you millions!

Comment: onEdit(e) trigger will only work if the user edits a cell.  It does not run if a formula is recalculated.  Also if the user cut/copy and pastes a range of cells e.range is only the upper left cell address of the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TheWizEd points out the value in T is dependant on the result in another cell. However an OnEdit function does not necessarily have to respond to the range where the change was made. I've used this code to use the OnEdit event to evaluate the values in Column T and then make the relevant change to values in Column S.

Column T uses a `for loop` to go through the various row, but the relevant value is pushed to array. This allows a single `setValues` to be executed at the end of the function.

The function should be assigned to the `OnEdit` trigger for the Spreadsheet.

```
function so_53469142() {

    // Setup spreadsheet and target sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("so_53469142");

    // get the last row of data
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // get range for Column  S & T
    var values = sheet.getRange(1, 19, lastRow, 2).getValues();

    // set counter variable
    var i = 0;
    var dataArray = [];
    var masterArray = [];


    // start loop
    for (i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
        // Logger.log("i="+i+", S = "+values[i][0]+", T = "+values[i][1]);//DEBUG

        // empty the array
        dataArray = [];

        // test value of first row in T
        if (values[i][1] === "Copied") {
            // If value = "Copies then push blank onto array for Column S
            dataArray.push("");
        } else {
            // else push existing value for column S
            dataArray.push(values[i][0]);
        }

        // make the array 2D
        masterArray.push(dataArray);

    }

    // Update values in Column S
    sheet.getRange(1, 19, lastRow).setValues(masterArray);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tedinoz!

Is that ok to run even though I edit other fields?

I am worried it is going to make my file very "heavy" and not that many times I will have "Copied" inserted.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thank you,

Comment: The problem here is that it will run the script only when the file is edited next time. So what happens now is that Copied stays there but only next time when another field is edited, then it removes the value from S:S. I need something that would run faster :(

Comment: @David Let's recap: the focus is each cell in Column T and adjacent Column S. Am I wrong? Each cell in Column T contains a formula, **you do not edit Column T**. Only changes in the value of one or more other cells affect the value of Column T. If/when the value in a cell in Column T = "Copied", then value in adjacent Column S should be deleted. Is that right? In all my testing, this happens immediately, there is no waiting for the "next" edit. David, what is the size of your spreadsheet, how many rows do you have in Column T, and how long does it take for your spreadsheet to recalculate?

Comment: Thank you, Tedinoz. You are right. For the speed of execution, I set a trigger that it runs the script on edit. So I add a value to the column S, then formula inside T after a minute shows "Copied" value. And when Copied is there, nothing happens, only when I edit another cell inside the sheet, then this script runs. I hope I explained it well. Please let me know if it is not clear. Thank you again for your time here! P.S. There are around 1000 rows but I can shorten it to 600 if necessary

Comment: Thanks, David. Two questions: 1) is the formula in T dependant on the value of S? 2) “So I add a value to the column S, then formula inside T **after a minute** shows "Copied" value”. Are you saying that the sheet takes a minute to recalculate?

Comment: It is, but there is another formula in between. So I add something in S, my second script runs and copies that value to another sheet. Once that is done, Copied shows up there. My second script runs every minute so it is not immediate. Thank you!!!

Comment: @David Please edit your question to provide full details (code and explanation) of the script that runs every minute, details (code and explanation) of the formula in Column T, and any other information relevant to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Done, @Tedinoz. Sorry, I didn't know it is important, now is all there. Please let me know if you have more questions and thanks for your help here, very appreciated!

Comment: @David Please add your code for the "minute" script.

Comment: @David What's the point of the formula in column T? The "minute" script copies the contents of S to V - so why not take it one step further and paste "Copied" into Column T and delete the value from Column S? I've got a script. Interested?

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, because it is more complicated than that. I have VLOOKUP and some other triggers to another file that are linked to this sheet. The point of formula in T:T is that it makes sure that that same value is copied inside V, then it triggers "Copied" and only then the S:S can be deleted. I am building a notepad, so I keep adding comments in S:S and those get transferred to V with that second script.

Comment: The reason why I want to delete automatically S:S is that the query will sometimes insert another row and my previous comments can move up or down, so if my second script keeps running, it will copy values to the wrong range. What I am doing at the moment is, I wait to see "Copied" and then I delete only those manually. It happesn that I have 15 values in S:S and the second script takes time so I can only delete S:S when T:T has Copied

Comment: @David The scenario you are describe is somewhat more complicated than than in your origination question. You would like something faster but in fact, your other scripts, formula, and processing are applying the brake, such as it is.  In fact, you are just as ‘at risk’ because your query may insert and/or move rows. I think this is as far as you are likely to get with this question.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz! Is it possible to run this one every hour? To set up hourly trigger execution instead of onEdit? Thank you!

Comment: @David Yes. Just change the trigger from OnEdit to time based.

Comment: @David “_the query will sometimes insert another row and my previous comments can move up or down, so if my second script keeps running, it will copy values to the wrong range_”. Pretty sure I took that into account when I wrote my alternate code- might be worth trying on a dummy spreadsheet. But on tangent, if this answer has been useful, consider accepting it, or voting for it.