# Cell Condition Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

This is the google sheet that I need a hand with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e4M5ptkinwLRwyQH4-ZSrDY3gp0ibjsuoTQvYmFX6GY/edit?usp=sharing

When I choose a category in Column A it automatically triggers the cell right to it to load a respective drop down list.

What I want is that when I would edit/delete category from a Column A - I want everything to be cleared in that particular row.

Can anyone please assist me with this one?

Comment: Do you mean that you want your script to check whether a cell in column A has been changed, and if so, to blank out columns B-I?   Have you tried to write any code to do that, or searched for simiar answers to that?

Comment: These two script answers may guide you in changing your script.  But if you are unsure how to make those changes, let us know.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716573/hide-columns-based-on-user-input-cell    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469142/clear-content-in-ss-when-tt-contains-copied-google-script

Comment: @kirkg13, I want my script to check whether a cell in column A has changed and if so - blank out everything to the right from the cell in that particular row.

Comment: Have you tried anything based on the script in that answer I pointed to above?   Basically you need an OnEdit script that checks whether the active cell is in column A, and is now blank, and then blanks the rest of that row.  Please show any code that what you've tried so far.